# How to simplify a sympy expression

Tags: python, sympy

Hello I have this sympy expression `0.5*c**2*m*(v/c)**2.0` and I want to bring it automatically to this form: `0.5*m*v**2`. I tried the sympy `simplify` function but that doesn't seem to work. What can I do? Thank you!

Comment: Could you clarify about what result `simplify` gives, and how this differs from what you are expecting?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco when I use simplify I get back the same form as the input one i.e. 0.5*c**2*m*(v/c)**2.0 instead of the desired one 0.5*m*v**2. I basically want the c**2 to get cancelled.

Answer (score 2):

These two expressions are not equivalent, only equivalent if c is not equal to 0. So if you want to get `0.5*m*v**2`, you need set c as a positive number:``

```py
>>> import sympy
>>> c= sympy.symbols('c',positive=True)
>>> m,v = sympy.symbols('m v')
>>> sympy.powsimp(0.5*c**2*m*(v/c)**2.0)
0.5*m*v**2.0
```

Besides, although `sympy.simplify` will give you what you want, I think `sympy.powsimp` is better. Because actually we want to reduce expression by combining powers with similar bases and exponents.

Comment: Thank you for this! But I am not sure how much this can help me in general. I don't always want the denominator to be positive and I don't always know what variable will end up in the denominator. In principle c can't be zero, so I am not sure why would that be a problem that sympy can't handle

Comment: Sorry for my carelessness. After plenty of tests, I noticed some abnormal behavior of `sympy`. If the parenthesis is followed by a power operation with a floating point power, `sympy` will not expand that parenthese. Specifying the sign of the variable or using integer powers can avoid this situation.

Comment: Thanks for this. Actually I am still confused. If I run simplify on this: expr = parse_expr("sqrt(x**2)"), I get back the same thing, which makes sense, as x can be, in general, complex. If I do x = symbols("x", positive=True), I would expect to get back "x", after running simplify, as there is no issue with that now. Yet I still get back "sqrt(x**2)". Why is that?